# Access to object from another activity

Tags: java, android, class, object

In my main *Activity* I have object with some data in it. I want to delete all this data through *PreferenceActivity* using method (*wipe()*) that does this job. How can I do it?

[image: Illustration]

Inside Preferences.java there is a *OnPreferenceClickListener* which, when activated, expected to use method in object that I need to access.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make this object as **static**.

Then you can access to this object by class name.

```
Activity.counters.wipe();
```

But, keeping data in activities is a bad practice in android development

Comment: I know two ways, but it may be more. First, you can contain data in Application class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html .Second, if your need only one Counters object you may made it as singletone. And contain data in Counters class as private static field with accessors. Hope, I help you, Roman. If you have more questions you may mail me and speak with me in russian :)